# How to receive WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK message in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I want handle WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK message in WPF application.
Here is my code:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ComponentDispatcher.ThreadFilterMessage += ComponentDispatcher_ThreadFilterMessage;
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }
    private void ComponentDispatcher_ThreadFilterMessage(ref MSG msg, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg.message == 0x0203)//WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK message
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

But I can't receive the WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK(0x0203) message. In this link( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645606(v=vs.85).aspx), I got know

> Only windows that have the CS_DBLCLKS style can receive WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK messages

I don't know how to set CS_DBLCLKS style in WPF window. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, can't find a way to set this style in wpf. But I solved in another way.
Calculate the time difference of two `WM_LBUTTONDBCLK` message, if the timespan bigger than DoubleClickTime(get by `GetDoubleClickTime()`) then do nothing.